# Mysql performance with LIKE '%%'

Tags: mysql

For a given query,

```
select * from contacts where name like "%$name%"
```

Does the mysql optimises the query to exclude the condition when a variable `$name` is empty?

When $name is empty string, will the query will be executed as

```
select * from contacts
```

or

```
select * from contacts where name like "%%"
```

Comment: Answer is NO. MySQL will return all the records

Comment: No, consider the behaviour of a NULL `name` with and without the WHERE clause.

Comment: Makes sense Alex. I didn't think of NULLs earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Alex K mentioned in the comments, MySQL won't do anything to optimise the like query.

In case you have null values in your rows, the query will not return those rows in the result set, which explains that there is a check on each row.
As suggested, it is best to have a check on your code and skip the like clause if the search value is empty.

Answer (score -1):

No,

Use a PHP condition to skip the query entirely in the event that $name is empty.

Comment: For anyone looking for the answer, note that my answer is correct and will help you (the vote down is note correct).